# Does there exist a real function‎ with the following properties?‎

Tags: real-analysis, limits, convex-analysis, monotone-functions

Does there exist a real function $f$ with the following properties?‎‎

‎
(a) ‎$‎f‎$ ‎is ‎positiv‎e function (‎$‎f‎\geq ‎0‎$‎).‎

‎
(a) ‎$‎f‎$ ‎is ‎concave ‎and ‎increasin‎g  on ‎$‎[1, +\infty)‎$‎.‎

‎
(b) ‎$‎‎‎‎‎\displaystyle{\lim_{n\to\infty}}‎(f(n) - f(n+1)) = 0‎$‎.‎‎

‎(c) ‎‎ ‎‎‎‎‎‎$‎\displaystyle{\lim_{x\to\infty}}‎‎f(x)\leq 0‎$.‎‎‎

Anyone ‎can ‎help ‎me. Thanks

Comment: Sure: $f(x) = 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the time of writing this answer, the four conditions in your question are

(a) ‎$‎f‎$ ‎is ‎positiv‎e function (‎$‎f‎\geq ‎0‎$‎).‎

‎
(a) ‎$‎f‎$ ‎is ‎concave ‎and ‎increasin‎g  on ‎$‎[1, +\infty)‎$‎.‎

‎
(b) ‎$‎‎‎‎‎\displaystyle{\lim_{n\to\infty}}‎(f(n) - f(n+1)) = 0‎$‎.‎‎

‎(c) ‎‎ ‎‎‎‎‎‎$‎\displaystyle{\lim_{x\to\infty}}‎‎f(x)\leq 0‎$.‎‎‎

A monotonically increasing function is smaller or equal to its limit when $x\to\infty$. If $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)\le 0$ (from (c)), and $f$ is increasing (from (a)), then it must hold that

$$f(x)\le 0\quad\mathrm{for}\ x\in[1,\infty).$$

But from the other (a), $f(x)\ge 0$ for all $x$. The only function that satisfies simultaneously both conditions is

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}0, & \mathrm{if}\ x\in[1,\infty) \\ \textrm{anything positive,} & \mathrm{if}\ x<1\end{cases}$$